# Trouble installing a script file of an addon (threejs export)

Tags: export, add-on, three.js

I placed the threejs script `export_threejs.py` in `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\scripts\addons`, but it does not show up in the addons list in *User Preferences*.

When I try to install manually nothing happens.

Comment: I keep getting this error "fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!:". I have tried it with the latest versions of Blender as well as version 2.65. In both I get the error, and the Threejs export import option is not visible. Any ideas on how to fix this? It seems other people are having the same issue...

Answer (score 2):

`export_threejs.py` is only part of an addon, you need all of files or it won't work.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs

A `__init__.py` is crucial, because it contains the `bl_info` dict to make it a Blender addon, and it loads the other files.

In your `...\scripts\addons\` folder, there needs to be a subfolder (e.g. called `io_mesh_threejs`) with all 3 files of the addon inside.

In order to use Blender's Addon *Install from file...* feature for addons with multiple files, the mentioned folder with the scripts (`io_mesh_threejs`) needs to be zipped and you select that zip-file.